# Using htaccess to strip domain name from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not even sure if this is possible but have been looking everywhere for a solution.  My site generates dynamic info about domain names and people can view their info in the following format:

```
http://www.mysite.com/analyze/yourdomain.com
```

The problem is that sometimes people will enter http:// or www or even the full URL instead of their domain, such as this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/analyze/http://www.yourdomain.com/this-is-a-test
```

What I'd like to do with htaccess is get the domain name and redirect it to the proper URL like the first one listed.

This is what I currently have for my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(xml|txt)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/review/$1 [R=301,L]

Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(xml|txt)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)$ review.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The main issue that I'm having is that every tutorial I find about stripping/redirecting domains is applying to my actual domain name, not the user's in the URL.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: > **sometimes people will enter http:// or www** Is it a direct link or user have to enter in a form ? If its a form you are better off validating inputs, much easier.

Comment: I do have a form and it works perfectly, but a lot of people tend to just type it in manually and get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding thie right below your first rule (that 301 redirects):

```
RewriteRule ^analyze/http:/+([^/]+)/? /analyze/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect requests like `http://www.mysite.com/analyze/http://www.yourdomain.com/this-is-a-test` to `http://www.mysite.com/analyze/yourdomain.com`.

Comment: It looks like your code is redirecting it to `http://www.mysite.com/analyze/http:/www.yourdomain.com/this-is-a-test` so basically it's removing the `/` and causing a 404 maybe.

Comment: @user1135462 Apache is stripping out the duplicated slashes, so that's apache's doing. The regex needed to be changed to account for that. Edited the question so that `http://` is replaced by `http:/+`

Comment: Just tried your new code and it's still happening.  FYI, the .htaccess file is in the `analyze` folder.

Comment: Just cleared cache to make sure that isn't what's causing this - both the new and old code you gave me seems to be doing the same thing :(

Comment: @user1135462 Oh... if it's in the "analyze" folder then this will never work. You'll need to remove the `^analyze/` from the pattern, replace it with just `^`. The location of the htaccess file determines what the rules must look like. The general assumption is that it's in your document root.

Comment: Would it be possible to also strip the www IF it exists?  Not all domains will contain www but if they do it would be great if that could be removed...

Comment: @user1135462 Change `http:/+([^/]+)/` to `http:/+(www\.)?([^/]+)/` and replace the `$1` with a `$2` in the rule's target